# How to change font of name in resume class document

Tags: fonts, resume

When I used `\documentclass{resume}`, everything is automatically in comic sans. I changed most of the document to sans serif using:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
...
{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont
```

But the top info like name and email are all still in comic sans and I cannot figure out how to change them. I see that there is a `\namestyle` in the resume class, but I can't figure out how to use. I appreciate any help!

Comment: You should make your code full MWE for testing solutions. With this, I can give you only a tip to use `fontspec` package and set different font with `\setmainfont{your font name here}`. That should set all text to your preferred font, except for monospace text.

Comment: Where did you get this class? I can't find it on CTAN.